# Which medical specialist should be consulted for anus polyp?

Tags: surgery, anus

Who is the appropriate Dr who can understand issue better and help accordingly?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your post. May I ask who diagnosed the anus polyp? Or is it something you have self-diagnosed? Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith: Once I diagnosed with one of the Surgen. But I wanted to confirm it and reverify it with expert

Comment: An analyst? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which medical specialist should be consulted for anal polyp?

A physician specialised in disorders of the colon, rectum and anus might be the person of choice.

This could be a **proctologist** (a physician specialised in [proctology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorectal_surgery)), or if this speciality is not recognised/available in your country, this could be a **colorectal surgeon**. In some cases (depending on the size of the anal polyp) a **gastroenterologist can also handle anal polyps (through endoscopic removal)**.

*I would suggest seeing the surgeon who diagnosed this anal polyp and discuss further management with him.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which country you are in, as well as location of where you live (rural vs city).

If you are going to a hospital, medical doctors specialized in surgery (general surgery) can help you with your problem.

Comment: I received two down votes for this answer. I would like to know why this answer is "appropriate". This answer was meant to start a discussion, as people live in different countries and have different health care systems. 

I live in Taiwan, which has a national healthcare system and although not completely "free", is subsidized compared to the health care system in the US. Patients can visit a teaching hospital, community hospital, as well as small clinics, but the doctor you would want to see should be specialized in General Surgery. In general surgery, there are other sub-specialties.

Comment: Sub-specialties include hepato (liver), cardiothoracic (heart/lung), colorectal (gastrointestine related). The best physician would be one who is specialized in general surgery, and sub-specialized in colorectal procedures.

Comment: Answers are not meant for starting discussions.